# Is it the right way to do what Im trying? Abstract static variable?

Tags: java, oop, static, abstract

Look on the code below. It seems to be like there is easier way to do it.

For each new `Class` I want to add to the system, I have to do the following in order to set the class variable(static -> maxPlayers)?

Something like Abstract static variable?

```
protected abstract class Class{
        protected abstract int getMaxPlayers();

        public class Soldier extends Class{
            public static final int maxPlayers = 4;

            @Override
            protected int getMaxPlayers() {
                return Soldier.maxPlayers;
            }
        }

        public class Demoman extends Class{
            public static final int maxPlayers = 2;

            @Override
            protected int getMaxPlayers() {
                return Demoman.maxPlayers;
            }
        }
        public class Scout extends Class{
            public static final int maxPlayers = 4;

            @Override
            protected int getMaxPlayers() {
                return Scout.maxPlayers;
            }
        }
        public class Medic extends Class{
            public static final int maxPlayers = 2;

            @Override
            protected int getMaxPlayers() {
                return Medic.maxPlayers;
            }
        }
    }
```

its just like i have to repeat this template:

```
public static final int maxPlayers = 2;

            @Override
            protected int getMaxPlayers() {
                return Medic.maxPlayers;
            }
```

And i think it is not correct to do so.

Comment: Why are they all inner classes?

Comment: Calling your class Class is not such a great idea - the name is already in use...

Comment: Yes. Thats true. It is only for the example. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Please come up with a better (more descriptive) title for your question as well.

Comment: Im trying to do something like "Abstract Static" variable.
I have to write a new static variable for every class.

Comment: For what purpose? What is the purpose of your code?

Comment: Perhaps using constants in one class? `MAX_SOLDIER`, `MAX_DEMOMEN`?

Comment: @hexafraction Good question. Is it even allowed (compilable) for an inner class to extend its outer class?

Comment: @iamnotmaynard Yes it's allowed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't name your class `Class` (not even for examples). Choose a better name.

Secondly, it seems like an [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) is what you really need here:

```
public enum Army {   
    SOLDIER(4),
    DEMOMAN(2),
    SCOUT(4),
    MEDIC(2);

    private final int maxPlayers;

    private Army(int maxPlayers) {
        this.maxPlayers = maxPlayers;
    }

    public int getMaxPlayers() {
        return maxPlayers;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1: Nice, clean solution. However, you need to change your first line.

Comment: The speed. That is what i was looking for.

Comment: I thought about this method again. When you do it this way. The int of maxPlayers is stored in the instance, and not like static. So it has alot of times declared. That is not exactly what i want it to be.

Comment: @Nirock. No it isn't initialized lot of times. As you notice, the field is `final`. It is only initialized once, when the constructor is called.

Comment: Yes, but the constructor is called for every instance. Every time i use Role.SOLDIER

Comment: @Nirock. And enum constructor is called, when the enum class is loaded first time by the classloader.

Comment: Ohh, thats makes more sense. Thanks alot!

Comment: @Nirock. Of course, it is called for every instance, as every instance has a different value for `maxPlayers`. What exactly is your issue?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't have an static variable in a base class that has a different value for each subclass (as far as I can tell, this is what you'd *ideally* want to do).

The way you did it is one option, another is using a non-static variable, as below.

And your variable should preferably have less scope than your getter function.

```
class Class
{
   private final int maxPlayers;

   Class(int max)
   {
      maxPlayers = max;
   }

   public int getMaxPlayers()
   {
      return maxPlayers;
   }
}

class Soldier extends Class
{
   Soldier()
   {
      super(4);
   }
}
```

To increase readability and modifiability, you may want to consider replacing `4` here with an `enum` or similar.

Another way:

```
abstract class Class
{
   public static int MAX_PLAYERS_SOLDIER = 4,
                     MAX_PLAYERS_DEMOMAN = 2,
                     ...;

   protected abstract int getMaxPlayers();
}

class Soldier extends Class
{
   @Override
   protected int getMaxPlayers()
   {
      return MAX_PLAYERS_SOLDIER;
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any static variable in his base class. It's a static method, that he is overriding in all his sub classes.

Comment: I don't either, but I read the question as that that's what he's trying to accomplish.